# Centered Top Navigation Menu with 2 Elements

Tags: html, css

Hi i'm encountering an absolute stupid problem. iam currently designing a website with an center which includes two elements, a logo and an navigation icon. Between these two things should be a space even if the site is resized due to a low resolution or a mobile device.

but they are overlapping constantly! i have no idea what i could do...
This is the current markup:

```html
<div id="navContainer">  
    <div id="topNav">
        <div id="logo"><img src="images/logo.png"/> </div>
        <div id="mobileNav"><a  href="#" ><img id="hamburger" src="images/navIcon.png"></a></div>
    </div>
```

and its styling:

```css
#navContainer {margin:0 auto;}
#navContainer:hover{background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);cursor: pointer; width:100%;}
#topNav{width:50%; margin:0 auto;}
#logo{text-align:left; min-width:250px;}
#mobileNav{text-align:right; position:relative; bottom:50px; }
```

my goal is to get the navigation working like: http://www.teehanlax.com/

Comment: You want to look into `Responsive Web Design`, more info here: http://tinyurl.com/bp84bzq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are adding more than you need to. If you take out the logo and mobileNav divs and float the link tag to the right you'll get what you're looking for.

```
<div id="navContainer">
    <div id="topNav">
        <img src="images/logo.png" />
        <a href="#"><img id="hamburger" src="images/navIcon.png"/></a>
    </div>
</div>

a{
    float:right;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/39QVp/

Answer (score 0):

I would add a size for both your divs since you are using images. Then float the elements left and right. That should fix your problem.

```css
#logo{text-align:left; min-width:250px; float:left;}
#mobileNav{text-align:right; position:relative; bottom:50px; float:right}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using absolute positioning for the images

```
#navContainer {margin:0 auto;}
#navContainer:hover{background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);cursor: pointer; width:100%;}
#topNav{width:50%; margin:0 auto;}
#logo{ min-width:250px;}
#logo img{position:absolute;left:0;} 
#hamburger{position:absolute;right:0;}
```

Comment: He will want to make sure and have **position:relative;** in the parent div so that it is not always on the left and right side of the window. Unless that is his intention. Nice solution though.

Comment: Base on the link he gave I assume he wants to keep both elements on the edge of its parent div.